# matrix function disturbance approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, matrix-calculus

Given a matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and some function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{N \times N} \to \mathbb{R}^N$, I have tried to understand how the function value  is affected when a small perturbation $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ added to the matrix.

Can I approximate $\phi(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{\epsilon})$ using $\phi(\mathbf{X})$ and $\mathbf{\epsilon}$?

I have thought some possible solutions such as the first order approximation like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1184378/339790). However, I don't how accommodate the solutions to my problem since $\phi$ maps matrix to vector.

Can anybody help me with this problem? Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Why not compute the gradients of $\phi_1, \dots, \phi_N : \mathbb{R}^{N \times N} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the gradient of the function (a third-order tensor) is calculated as
$${\cal G} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} \quad\implies
{\cal G}_{ijk} = \frac{\partial \phi_{i}}{\partial X_{jk}}$$ 
Then the first two terms of the Taylor expansion are
$$\eqalign{
\phi(X+E) &= \phi(X) + {\cal G}:E \\
}$$
The double-dot product is more clearly expressed using index notation
$$\eqalign{
\big({\cal G}:E\big)_i &= \sum_{j}\sum_{k}{\cal G}_{ijk}\,E_{jk} \\
}$$